# iOS - Change storyboards upon rotation - Problems with Portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Ok so I have been testing out my own methods for changing the presented storyboards upon rotation and have been doing so with the `-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` method to be assigning `self` to another method which runs an if-else statement which checks the orientation and loads the correct storyboard appropriately. The problem I'm having is the checking if it's in portrait mode or the else part of the statement. When I run the app in simulator and rotate the device to landscape, it loads the landscape storyboard like it should. But when I rotate the device back to portrait mode, it doesn't change back to the portrait storyboard. At first I thought the problem was that I wasn't dismissing the view controllers but after doing that, it still didn't work. I realized that it was the else part of the statement that wasn't working. I stuck an`NSLog(@"PMComplete")` and still after running the app again and rotating to landscape and back, it still didn't show up in the log. Does anyone have any thoughts on what's wrong here? I am operating this on the viewcontroller for the portrait storyboard (assigned the view controller in the portrait storyboard the ViewController class). I also created this app without storyboards and created them from scratch and assigned the portrait one as the one that loads up from the AppDelegate.

Here is my ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize isLandscape;
@synthesize isPortrait;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewChanged {

    UIInterfaceOrientation theOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    UIStoryboard *portraitStoryboard;
    UIStoryboard *landscapeStoryboard;
    portraitStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    landscapeStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LandscapeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *portraitViewController = [portraitStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    UIViewController *landscapeViewController = [landscapeStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    if (theOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        theOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        [portraitViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self presentViewController:landscapeViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"LSComplete");


    }else{
        [landscapeViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self presentViewController:portraitViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"PMComplete");
    }

}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    [self viewChanged];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I suggest you to use one viewcontroller instead, just manipulate the frames.